# Odd regexp behaviour - matches only first and last capture group

Tags: c#, regex, perl, capture

I am trying to write a regexp which would match a comma separated list of words and capture all words. This line should be matched    `apple , banana     ,orange,peanut`  and captures should  be `apple`, `banana`, `orange`, `peanut`. To do that I use following regexp:

```
^\s*([a-z_]\w*)(?:\s*,\s*([a-z_]\w*))*\s*$
```

It successfully matches the string but all of a sudden only `apple` and `peanut` are captured. This behaviour is seen in both C# and Perl. Thus I assume I am missing something about how regexp matching works. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value given by `match.Groups[2].Value` is just the *last* value captured by the second group.

To find *all* the values, look at `match.Groups[2].Captures[i].Value` where in this case `i` ranges from `0` to `2`. (As well as `match.Groups[1].Value` for the first group.)

(+1 for question, I learned something today!)

Comment: +1 I was not sure if .net has this feature and was too lazy to check.

Comment: @stema I didn't even realise this was an issue, I thought all the values would turn up in `Groups`!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at `.Captures` collection! Eventually I came up with using same regexp as I put in the question and then I do `for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++) foreach (var capture in match.Groups[i].Captures) { ... do smth with capture ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string text = "   apple , banana ,orange,peanut";

var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\s*(?<word>\w+)\s*,?")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups["word"].Value)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: PS: This is a good site to test regular expressions in .NET:

[Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: I like [this one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=([A-Z]{2})([0-3])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\d{2})(\d{3})&i=KT2140210456).

Comment: Thanks @bazzilic and ChankeyPathak, I didn't know those websites.

Answer (score 2):

You are [repeating your capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), at every repeated match the previous content is overwritten. So only the last match of your second capturing group is available at the end.

You can change your second capturing group to

```
^\s*([a-z_]\w*)((?:\s*,\s*(?:[a-z_]\w*))*)\s*$
```

Then the result would be " , banana ,orange,peanut" in your second group. I am not sure, if you want this.

If you want to check that the string has that pattern and extract each word. I would do it in two steps.

1. Check the pattern with your regex.
2. If the pattern is correct, remove leading and trailing whitespace and split on `\s*,\s*`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple regexp:

`(?:^| *)(.+?)(?:,|$)`

Explanation:

```
?:    # Non capturing group
^| *  # Match start of line or multiple spaces
.+    # Capture the word in the list, lazy
?:    # Non capture group
,|$   # Match comma or end of line
```

*Note: [Rublular](http://rubular.com/r/Jye97F5FTx) is a nice website for testing this kind of thing.*